# Facing issue with react- after npm start

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2

```
learnreact@1.0.0 start C:\Users\Vaibhav\Desktop\reactApp
webpack-dev-server

'webpack-dev-server' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! learnreact@1.0.0 start: `webpack-dev-server`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the learnreact@1.0.0 start script 'webpack-dev-server'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the learnreact package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     webpack-dev-server
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs learnreact
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls learnreact
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Vaibhav\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-04-22T13_06_29_371Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Have you installed the dev server with `npm install webpack-dev-server --save-dev`?

Comment: yes, I have followed the steps mentioned here- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs/reactjs_environment_setup.htm

Answer (score -1):

If you have installed it, the executable is under node_modules/.bin
You could use

```
./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server
```

or

```
$(npm bin)/webpack-dev-server
```

Comment: If it's installed, and the executable is under `./node_modules/.bin`, adding the full path is pointless since `npm start` (and all npm scripts) already have `./node_modules/.bin` available on the path.